# How to print random number of times one drawing in canvas javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, random

I have a canvas and I draw a rectangle in one function, in a new function I need to print this square a random number of times between 5 and 10.

I know I have to use  `Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 5` but now what I need to do to print the rectangle randomly 5 or 10 times.

This is what I've got so far, but not sure how to make it work

```
function rectangle() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function randomRect(){
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 5;
  rectangle()
}
```

Comment: You need a loop over `let count = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 5;`, you'll also need to adjust the starting place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Math.random` as a parameter inside a `for` loop.

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');

function rectangle(x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x, y, 50, 50);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function randomRect() {
  const squareCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 5;
  for (var i = 0; i < squareCount; i++) {
    // Stagger the x,y position so the squares aren't on top of each other
    rectangle(i * 10, i * 10);
  };
};

randomRect()
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px dashed firebrick;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Tempted to -1, all rects will be rendered on top of each other, maybe you can pass in the x,y coordinates to `rectangle(x, y)`

Comment: I am aware of that. The OP asks for a way to run a function multiple times. NOT how to randomize where to put the rectangles.

Comment: Well, I see your point but answering a question that doesn't make sense doesn't make sense... :) You have to at least mention the obvious shortcoming of your solution and either write the solution or even better, ask the OP to try  your suggestion so they can learn